# Ef not filtering 1:Many relationship properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I got into a problem where I cannot filter properly the linq Relationship which is 1-Many using a.ListOfEntities.Any(t=>t.Id==id); the result is not what i want to filter here are my codes

**Details Entity**

```
public class RequestCollection : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public virtual  SubjectRequest Request { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public  virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent Entity**

```
 public class SubjectRequest : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Open { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestCollection> RequestCollections { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Initiator { get; set; }
    public virtual  Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent Mapping**

```
public class RequestCollectionMap :EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestCollection>
{
    public RequestCollectionMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Request)
            .WithMany(t => t.RequestCollections)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RequestId);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Student)
            .WithMany(t => t.Requests)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.StudentId);


    }
}

public class SubjectRequestMap :EntityTypeConfiguration<SubjectRequest>
{
    public SubjectRequestMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.HasMany(t => t.RequestCollections)
            .WithRequired(t => t.Request)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RequestId);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Initiator)
            .WithMany(t => t.SubjectRequests)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.StudentId);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Subject)
            .WithMany(t => t.Requests)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.SubjectId);
    }
}
```

and here is the code that filters wrong where my aim is to filter out the subject request suitable for the students based on his year, college and course but eliminates where he currently joins but it filters out wrong.

```
return
            _repository.Query(a => a.Subject.SemesterYear == year && a.Subject.CourseId == courseId &&!a.RequestCollections.Any(a=>a.StudentId==studentId))
                .Include(a => a.Subject)
                .Include(a=> a.Subject.College)
                .Include(a => a.Initiator)
                .Include(a => a.RequestCollections)
                .Select(a => new RequestGridSource()
                {
                    Id = a.Id,
                    CreationDate = a.CreationDate,
                    Initiator = a.Initiator.FirstName + " " + a.Initiator.LastName,
                    Open = a.Open,
                    Reason = a.Reason,
                    Semester = a.Semester,
                    Status = a.Status,
                    Subject = a.Subject.Code,
                    Year = a.Year,
                    PhotoUrl = a.Subject.College.PhotoPath,
                    TotalCount = a.RequestCollections.Count
                }).AsQueryable();
```

Database Query Sent

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
[Extent1].[SubjectId] AS [SubjectId], 
[Extent1].[Reason] AS [Reason], 
[Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
[Extent1].[Semester] AS [Semester], 
[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Extent1].[Open] AS [Open]
FROM  [dbo].[SubjectRequests] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subjects] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SubjectId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE ([Extent2].[SemesterYear] = 5) AND ([Extent2].[CourseId] = 2) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[RequestCollections] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[RequestId]
))
```

If i will remove the line  **WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[RequestId]** the output will be correct

here are my Records in the Request Collections DB

```
Id  JoinDate               RequestId    StudentId   Reason
62  2017-03-24 11:29:06.237   1            1         NULL
71  2017-03-28 12:51:07.060   4            4         NULL
72  2017-03-28 12:51:08.153   7            4         NULL
73  2017-03-28 12:51:08.853   5            4         NULL
87  2017-03-29 18:00:58.117   6            18        NULL
88  2017-03-29 18:01:20.797   9            18        NULL
101 2017-03-29 23:10:56.917   12           2         NULL
```

Subject Request

```
Id  StudentId   SubjectId   Reason  Year    Semester    CreationDate    Status  Open
6   2   89  Reason  5   2   2017-03-24 16:42:30.447 CLOSED  0
8   2   90  Reason  5   2   2017-03-29 13:37:45.827 CLOSED  0
9   2   93  Reason  5   2   2017-03-29 14:54:13.810 CLOSED  0
10  2   94  Reason  5   1   2017-03-29 16:24:16.540 PENDING 0
11  17  106 Reason  5   2   2017-03-29 17:43:41.353 PENDING 0
12  2   105 Reason  5   2   2017-03-29 18:09:46.413 PENDING 0
```

Here is the code that Filters but not so clean because i need to get the separate list from the database then group it by the requestId

```
 var req= _requestService.GetGridSources(student.Id,student.CourseId,student.Year);
        var collections = _collectionService.GetStudentRequests(student.Id);
        var result = req.Concat(collections)
                         .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                         .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                         .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                         .ToList();
        return result;
```

The first List gets All the possible request based on the students standing and the second list gets the request he joined and group it by requestId. 
Is it possible that its a bug somewhere in EF or someone can point out what is wrong with my code..

Comment: The SQL query doesn't seem to match the LINQ query posted. Did you try to execute it separately (`collections.ToList()`) or take `collections.ToString()` from it to see the SQL before `Concat`?

Comment: that is exactly what query it emits. if i remove the said line it has the right results